# Issue installing .apk with PackageInstaller

Tags: java, android

My goal is to install an .apk file that's stored on the device. I tried using ACTION_VIEW intent, but it's deprecated as of Android 10, I believe.

I've already scoured half the web, but most answers are either using the deprecated intents, kotlin or just don't work.

Here's my code

```
 private void installApk() throws IOException {
        if (!requireContext().getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES,
                    Uri.parse("package:" + requireContext().getPackageName())));
        } else {

//            Log.d(TAG, "File Exists?: " + outputFile.exists() + " ; " + outputFile.getAbsolutePath() + " ; " + "can read?" + outputFile.canRead() + " ; " + "can write?" + outputFile.canWrite());
            PackageInstaller packageInstaller = requireContext().getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
            PackageInstaller.SessionParams params = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller
                    .SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
            int sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params);
            PackageInstaller.Session session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);

                addApkToInstallSession(session);

                Intent callbackIntent = new Intent(requireContext(), APKInstallService.class);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(requireContext(), 0, callbackIntent, 0);
                // This is sending the result of the installation to the APKInstallService.
                IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();
                session.commit(statusReceiver);


        }
    }
```

This is the method I call in my onClickListener

```
  private void addApkToInstallSession(PackageInstaller.Session session)
            throws IOException {
        try (OutputStream packageInSession = session.openWrite("package", 0, -1);
             InputStream is = requireContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileURI)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
            int n;
            while ((n = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                packageInSession.write(buffer, 0, n);
            }
        }
    }
```

Adding the file to the session.

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInstaller;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class APKInstallService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "APKInstallService";


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int status = intent.getIntExtra(PackageInstaller.EXTRA_STATUS, -999);

        switch (status) {
            case PackageInstaller.STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION:
                Log.d(TAG, "Requesting user confirmation for installation");
                // This is a way to get the intent that was passed to the service.
                //Intent confirmationIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
                //confirmationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                //try {
                  //  startActivity(confirmationIntent);
                //} catch (Exception e) {
                    //No action

//                }
                break;
            case PackageInstaller.STATUS_SUCCESS:
                Log.d(TAG, "Installation succeed");
                break;
            default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Installation failed");
                break;
        }
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Getting the result

I'm fairly new to coding, so sorry if this is a dumb issue

Comment: "Getting the result" -- you failed to explain what your results are. FWIW, [this sample Kotlin project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller), profiled in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Q), demonstrates the use of `PackageInstaller`.

Comment: While the sample is in Kotiln, at least [the relevant book chapter is in English](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-pkg-001.html), and perhaps it will give you some ideas.

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you for the code sample. It appears that the reason my solution in the question didn't work was because of the emulator, rather than the code. It started working when I used one with google services installed, it looks like that's a requirement, even though it's not stated anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue was in the fact that my emulator didn't have gapps installed, which is, even though not stated anywhere, apparently a dependency for this kind of action. Although I would recommend the chapters that CommonsWare brought up in his comment, as they were much more comprehensive than the scarce documentation.